# Is good to save in sharedPreferences a 47k set informations? And a fragment result?

Tags: android, fragment, sharedpreferences

I have to download a `List`of 47k airports from Parse. I want to save it and use when I need, so I think that convert List to `HashSet` and save it in `SharedPreferencies`. 
It's a good thing or I make my application slow?

Then I want to show in a `listView` this `Set`. So I decide to add new 
`fragment`, check the item, return this value and do `popBackStack()`. It's also a good way to do it?

Comment: `Is good to save in sharedPreferences a 47k set informations?` NO, `NO` and **NO**. Did I already say "NO"? SharedPreferences are to be used only for a small amount of data (10, 100 items, ...). For such a large amount of data, you want to use a database, instead.

Comment: @LonnieZamora SQLite databases? I hate it..are there other options, like files?

Comment: You probably fear what you don't know. Files **could** be used, but they are **highly inefficient**. Whereas a database gives you the speed and the flexibility of making on the fly searches, sums, averages, sortings, ...

Comment: but what is the best efficient mode to pass this data into activity? Have I to call database every time I need? It's expensive, I try it in background asynctask and it gives me result after 5-10 seconds

Comment: Of course it really depends. Given that your database is **offline**, try **indexing** your database on the fields which are used in WHERE clauses and in JOINS (if you have more related tables - as a good database structure will suppose). You'll be surprised of the speed boost. 10 secs will easily become 25 ms.

Comment: You do know that Parse has offline database support called Local Datastore?

Comment: @LonnieZamora I have only SELECT x FROM y.. the time perhaps depends of 47k elements...

Comment: @cYrixmorten yes, but one request of this project is to avoid Local Datastore

Comment: Could you tell us **why on earth** do you need to fetch **all 47000 records at once**? Can't it be easier to get only the 1, 5 or 10 records you need from time to time? This would be really lightning-fast.

Comment: @Lonnie Zamora because I must show the result in listview, if I download 10 airports any time it works also?

Comment: Of course. You don't have to preload the ListView with ALL the airports in the world. Just show the ones in the area of interest (which is where a search will help). Therefore, you might have to load only the airports in West Virginia (so to speak) And a simple `SELECT * FROM Airports WHERE Location = 'West Virginia'` will return no more than 45 results. Which is quite manageable. You should always transfer the **least useful amount of data**. And get great results at no time cost.

Comment: Is it also possible to use an editText instead of listview? So with autocomplete text I avoid the list

Comment: For searching the locations, yes. But for displaying the results a tabular list is preferrable.

Comment: Thanks man, you help me a lot!

Comment: Glad to know that.

Comment: Would you care to explain why you need to avoid local datastore? Under the hood it merely simplifies interacting with an sqlite database. Of course many other libraries exists that performs the same level of abstraction, but LDS seems obvious since you are using Parse.